# Changing base::colnames into a generic function called colnames

Tags: r, generics, methods, zoo

I am developing a package and I want to use `colnames()` to extract an attribute from a list.

```
#' @export
colnames <- function(x) {
  UseMethod("colnames")
}

#' @export
colnames.default <- function(x) {
   base::colnames(x)
 }

#' @export
colnames.newclass <- function(x) {
  some_sort_of_subsetting(x)
}
```

Is this legit? When I will attach the package it will mask `base::colnames()` but I use it as a default, with the only exception of my own class "newclass".

Also on the same note. I want to use zoo::index() generic as a name, What are your suggestions? To add zoo to Depends or to make a new generic function.

```
#' @export
index <- function(x, ...) {
   UseMethod("index")
}
```

And then do I have to make a reference to zoo in case the user loads zoo as well? Can I import just the generic function from zoo?

Comment: Can you not just copy and paste the code from `base` `colnames` into your package?

Comment: This is not what I want. Maybe I haven't described it properly. I want to keep colnames use for common objects (e.g. data.frame) but I want it to do a different thing when I use it for "newclass" object. I am asking whether my way is correct, or if there is another better way?